# How to notify a thread when element is added to list

Tags: java

I have 2 threads. First is adding to list what he gets from network. Second is checking a list for proper packet. When he check a list and wont find a packet it should wait max n seconds and return null. How to make when thread is waiting and list have been modified this thread wake up.

Comment: Sounds like you need to [learn](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077258/learn-java/observer-and-observable.html) about [Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) and [Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try waiting on a [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) with the `poll(timeout, unit)` method.

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting up to the specified wait time if necessary for an element to become available.'''

This will take care of the signalling issues as well as the synchronization.

Comment: Thx for help. But i need something like "BlockingList" because sometimes i need to take elements from middle of collection.